# How to add alternate function to back button in action bar Android

Tags: android

Ultimately, this new method that would be called when the back button is pressed will perform the same task as the normal back button does: switching to the previous `Activity`. However, I would also like to pass a `String` of text along to the previous `Activity`. The default back button method does not do this. I need to find a way so that I can pass a `String` back to the other action.

An example would be simply using an `Intent` along with the `putExtra()` method, allowing me to pass the `String` successfully.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I might accomplish this?

Please let me know if I am unclear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult as [this example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example).

FirstActivity.class, you can call openOther()

```
public int REQUEST_CODE = 123;
private void openOther(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE){
        Log.d("Example","This is...");
        // your code here
    }

}
```

In SecondActivity.class, you can call sendToFirst()

```
public void sendToFirst(int resultcode)
{
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("data", "Your String...");
    setResult(resultcode, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you create the custom xml layout for action bar.

Then, get your default Action bar and set custom view.

Finally, set button onCLickListener in your custom layout as usually does .

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_3, null);
TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
mTitleTextView.setText(R.string.title_activity_main);
mTitleTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);



ImageButton imageButtoan = (ImageButton) mCustomView
        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageButtoan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }
});

mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```